# Assign 'this' reference to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Is it possible to assign 'this' reference to a variable in javascript. What I want is:

```
var someVariable = this;
alert(someVariable);
```

But I'm getting alert saying 'undefined'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to assign `this` to a variable. When you get `undefined`, then you probably use/alert the variable outside the scope where it was defined.

This will work:

```
var someVariable;
function someFunction () {
    someVariable = this;
}
new someFunction();
alert(someVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks Frederik for your quic response, I think my scope is fine because I've declare someVariable globally. For your information, in the context of 'this', it is containing a html form.

Comment: What do you mean by "`this` is containing a HTML form`? Can you show us a bit more code?

Comment: When you assigned it as a global variable, make sure that you don't use `var` again when you assign it to `this`. That would reassign the variable within the current scope, so that it won't be available outside the scope.

Comment: Thanks Frederik, it's working. My variable was not is valid scope, but I could not realize that.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.