# Multiple this, use the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case, I have `this` in each(), I need to use that this from the begining, I know it's blur but you'll understand with the example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.ids-attributes-wrapper').each(function(){
            var size_li = jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters').length;
            x=3;
            jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters:gt('+x+')').hide().end().append(jQuery('<li class="ids-sub-filters more">...</li>'));
            jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li:lt('+x+')').show();
            jQuery(this).find('#show-more').click(function () {
                x= (x+50 <= size_li) ? x+50 : size_li;
                jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li:lt('+x+')').show(); 
               //!!! HERE the above this 'jQuery(this)' doesn't refer to the .ids-attributes-wrapper each selector
                jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters.more').remove();
            });
            jQuery(this).find('#show-less').click(function () {
                if (!jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters').hasClass('more')) {
                    x = 5;
                    jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
                    jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters:gt('+x+')').hide().end().append(jQuery('<li class="ids-sub-filters more">...</li>'));
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: If I understand correctly,  assign this to local variable and use that local variable at place where you are using this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign 'this' reference to a variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627344/assign-this-reference-to-a-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: @Atul yes it's a solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` context problems in JavaScript are pretty common. I believe that what you are looking for is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.ids-attributes-wrapper').each(function(){
            var size_li = jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters').length;
            x=3;
            jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters:gt('+x+')').hide().end().append(jQuery('<li class="ids-sub-filters more">...</li>'));
            jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li:lt('+x+')').show();
            var self=this
            jQuery(this).find('#show-more').click(function () {
                x= (x+50 <= size_li) ? x+50 : size_li;
                jQuery(self).find('dd.ids-attr-content li:lt('+x+')').show(); 
               //!!! HERE the above this 'jQuery(this)' doesn't refer to the .ids-attributes-wrapper each selector
                jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters.more').remove();
            });
            jQuery(this).find('#show-less').click(function () {
                if (!jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters').hasClass('more')) {
                    x = 5;
                    jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
                    jQuery(this).find('dd.ids-attr-content li.ids-sub-filters:gt('+x+')').hide().end().append(jQuery('<li class="ids-sub-filters more">...</li>'));
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

In this example, the context from the previous `this` is referenced by the new variable `self`. Also, JavaScript has a built in language feature to handle this. It's the `bind` function, but it's not used very often and the `self` method I have demonstrated here is more idiomatic.